# C# parse Guid? from XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, guid, ternary-operator

How can I initialize my nullable Guid to **null** if the **attribute** is not present?

Something like that:

```
this.SessionId = metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId") == null ? null : new Guid(metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId").Value);
```

With this code I have this error :

```
type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.Guid'
```

What is the best way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the `null` explicitly to a `Guid?` to help the compiler:

```
this.SessionId = metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId") == null ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(object)DBNull.Value` should do it

```
   this.SessionId = metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId")== null ? (object)DBNull.Value : Guid(metadata.Root.Attribute("SessionId").Value)
```